# Is it possible to access VueX Getters during dynamic component registration

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex

Is it possible to access VueX store getters when defining a dynamic component using webpack?

I'm using multiple modules inside my store.

Example:

```js
components: {
  'some-template': () => {
    const someVal = this.$store.getters.someVal;
    return System.import(`./some-template/${someVal}.vue`)
  }
}
```

Main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import { someStore } from ./stores/some-store'
import { otherStore } from ./stores/other-store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: new VueX.Store({
    modules: {
      someStore,
      otherStore
    }
  })
})
```

Store example:

```js
export const someStore = {
  state: { 
    someVal: 'blah'
  },
  
  getters: {
    someVal(state) {
      return state.someVal;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem in your code? I think `this.$store.getters.someVal` might trigger an error. If yes, you should try import store directly then use as `store.getters.someVal`

Comment: Store is not defined and importing the module directly doesn’t work since it’s a module and not a vuex instance

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you use `new VueX.Store` on main.js file I always create a separate file called `store.js` then import it into main.js and this is the file I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

To work around the issue with modules, I instead created an app store that will default using new Vuex instance, then dynamically add modules as needed. That way, I can import the store where needed and access the getters